# retrieve rows within 5 minutes of the timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need the rows in a table to show only the last 5 minutes data using the `timestamp` column.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried using

```
select * from [table_name]
where [timestamp] < datediff(minute,-5,getdate())
```

Comment: Can the column contain future values? If so, you might need to add another condition (or change it to a BETWEEN)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You need to use DATEADD instead.

```
select * 
from [table_name] 
where [timestamp] > dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```